# Contar elementos numa gama de valores

Tags: c++, array

Existe alguma forma mais concisa de contar todos os elementos de um vector (aqui no exemplo entre 10 e 20) do que a apresentada?

```
vector<int> v={1,2,3,45,24,10,20,-90,100,18,17,15,87};
    int n;
    for (int i=0;i<v.size();i++){
        if (v[i]>=10 && v[i]<=20)
            n++;
    }
    cout << n;
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 5):

Essencialmente não e mesmo que tenha não sei se deveria ser aplicada. Legibilidade é uma característica mais importante. Eu até consigo pensar em algumas coisas que poupam alguns poucos caracteres, mas pra que? Já acho que este código está ilegível demais.

Tem maneiras diferentes, mas não mais concisas e performáticas.

Se abrir mão de um pouco de performance dá para fazer assim:

```
int main() {
    vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 45, 24, 10, 20, -90, 100, 18, 17, 15, 87 };
    cout << count_if(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), [](int i) { return i >= 10 && i <= 20;});
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/dZEJVf). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ujauryuk-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Vector/CountIf.cpp).

Alguns dirão que ficou pior.

Comment: Ilegível? Como poderia torna-lo mais legível?

Comment: Claro que ele é muito simples para falar que não dá para entender mas tem algumas práticas comuns  que ficaria melhor para acostumar sempre fazer o ideal quando isto for mais importante. Dar melhor nome para as variável, especialmente a que faz a contagem e o vetor. Dar mais espaços entre os operadores. Nada grave. Nem poderia ser em algo tão simples.

Answer (score 3):

Não será certamente a forma mais concisa, mas evita usar um ciclo para percorrer todos os elementos do vector. Neste caso utiliza-se um algoritmo da linguagem (definido no cabeçalho `<algorithm>`) para contar os elementos que obedecem à função `predicado`. Se quiser mais informações sobre `count_if`, recomendo http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/count_if/.

Os dois primeiros parâmetros são os iteradores para as posições inicial e final do vector (dado que se pretende percorrê-lo na íntegra) e o terceiro é uma função que aceita um valor do vector e verifica se a condição é válida para a contagem, devolvendo `true` neste caso e `false` caso contrário.

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

bool predicado (int i) {
    return (i>=10 && i<=20);
}

int main(){
    vector<int> v={1,2,3,45,24,10,20,-90,100,18,17,15,87};
    cout << count_if(v.cbegin(), v.cend(), predicado);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isso pode ser feito com uma *lambda* também: `[](int i){return (i>=10 && i<=20);}`. Por outro lado eu acho que esse idioma mais funcional só faria sentido se existem vários predicados intercambiáveis. Exemplos, funções de predicado de `range` +  funções de predicado de índice, etc.